# Posting data between multiple domains whilst keeping server side

Tags: php, session, curl, iis, url-rewriting

I need to share a simple URL to our customers who will be posting data to it.

For example https://data.mysite.com

Depending on the values that are received I then need the above script to post the data it has received along with additionally generated data along with the user to another server / domain (decided by the script).

For example:-

user1 > post data > https://data.mysite.com  > re-post data & user > https://eastcoast.server1.com

user2 > post data > https://data.mysite.com  > re-post data & user > https://westcoast.server2.com

I don't want the data to be accessible at any time client side i.e. need to keep it server side.

I believe I can't use sessions due to the different domains that i need to work between.

I have tried a curl request with followlocation but believe this won't work either.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a situation where you might want to implement an API for servers at westcoast and eastcoast. The application at mysite.com would call the appropriate API on each server to send the data. 
The request between servers would include the user info as requested and allow for transfer of the data.

Also you can try looking into mysql replication to see if that might be of use in your situation.